# how can match two list and remove duplicate based on condition on dictionary in list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, object

I want to merge two lists and get data matched without duplicates and to alias them to new structure
I have two lists

here is a given two list try to merge

```py
cats = [
    'orange', 'apple', 'banana'
]
```

and second list

```py
types = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "orange"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "apple"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "type": "apple"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "type": "orange"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "type": "banana"
    }
]
```

and I want to combine them to get this result:

```py
[
    {'orange': {
        'UNIT': [1, 4]
    }
    },
    {'apple': {
        'UNIT': [2, 3]
    }
    },
    {'banana': {
        'UNIT': [5]
    }
    }
]
```

and my code, this after my tries i get this result :

```py
for item in types:
    for cat in cats:
        if item['type'] == cat:
     
            matched.append(
                {
                    cat: {
                        "UNIT": [i['id'] for i in types if
                                 'id' in i]
                    }
                }
            )
```

and my result is like this

```py
[{'orange': {'UNIT': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}},
 {'apple': {'UNIT': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}},
 {'apple': {'UNIT': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}},
 {'orange': {'UNIT': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}},
 {'banana': {'UNIT': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}}]
```

Comment: Nice 1st post, clear - concise, with code, structured: "what I have, what I want, what I tried, what I get".

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension:

```
[{cat:{'UNIT':[type_['id'] for type_ in types if type_['type'] == cat]}} for cat in cats]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `in` inside your list comprehension - beside that your code is complex. You get multiples due to your for loops and never checking if that fruit was already added to `matched`.

To reduce the 2 lists to the needed values you can use

```
cats = [    'orange', 'apple', 'banana']

types = [    { "id": 1, "type": "orange" },
    { "id": 2, "type": "apple" },
    { "id": 3, "type": "apple" },
    { "id": 4, "type": "orange" },
    { "id": 5, "type": "banana" }]

rv = {}
for inner in types:
    t = inner["type"]
    if t not in cats: # for current data not needed, only needed
        continue      # if some listelements don't occure in dict
    rv.setdefault(t, [])
    rv[t].append(inner["id"])
        
print(rv)
```

which leads to an easier dictionary with all the data you need:

```
{'orange': [1, 4], 'apple': [2, 3], 'banana': [5]}
```

From there you can build up your overly complex list of dicts with 1 key each:

```
lv = [{k:{"UNIT":v}} for k,v in rv.items()]
print (lv)
```

to get

```
[{'orange': {'UNIT': [1, 4]}}, 
 {'apple': {'UNIT': [2, 3]}}, 
 {'banana': {'UNIT': [5]}}]
```

---

Answer to extended problem from comment:
If you need to add more things you need to capture you can leverage the fact that lists and dicts store by ref:

```
cats = [    'orange', 'apple', 'banana']
types = [    { "id": 1, "type": "orange" , "bouncyness": 42 },
             { "id": 2, "type": "apple"  , "bouncyness": 21 },    
             {"id": 3, "type": "apple"  , "bouncyness": 63},    
             { "id": 4, "type": "orange"  , "bouncyness": 84},    
             { "id": 5, "type": "banana"  , "bouncyness": 99}]

rv = []   # list of dicts - single key is "fruitname"
pil = {}  # dict that keeps track which fruit is on what position in rv
          # to avoid iterating over list to find correct fruit-dict

di = None # the current fruits dictionary 

for inner in types:
    t = inner["type"]
    if t not in cats: # for current data not needed, only needed
        continue      # if some listelements don't occure in dict

    # step1: find correct fruit dict in rv or create new one and add it
    di = None
    if t in pil:
        # get cached dict by position of fruit in rv
        di = rv[pil[t]]
    else:
        # create fruit dict, cache position in rv in pil
        di = {}
        rv.append(di)
        pil[t] = len(rv)-1

    # step2: create all the needed inner lists         
    #   you can speed this up using defaultdict(list) if speed gets
    #   problematic - until then dict.setdefault should be fine
    di.setdefault(t, [])
    di.setdefault("bouncyness", [])

    # step3: fill with values
    di[t].append(inner["id"])
    di["bouncyness"].append(inner["bouncyness"])
        
print(rv)
```

to get

```
[{'orange': [1, 4], 'bouncyness': [42, 84]}, 
 {'apple': [2, 3], 'bouncyness': [21, 63]}, 
 {'banana': [5], 'bouncyness': [99]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) method and lambda.

```py
dict_lst = []
for cat in cats:
    cat_items = filter(lambda x: x['type'] == cat, types)
    cat_dict = {cat: {'UNIT': [x['id'] for x in cat_items]}} 
    dict_lst.append(cat_dict)
print(dict_lst)
```

---

```
[{'orange': {'UNIT': [1, 4]}},
 {'apple': {'UNIT': [2, 3]}},
 {'banana': {'UNIT': [5]}}]
```